# How to Pass TimeSpan Variable to Data base

Tags: vb.net, string

I have the code Like this:

```
Dim starttime As TimeSpan = fromtimepicker.Value.TimeOfDay
Dim endtime As TimeSpan = TotimePicker.Value.TimeOfDay
```

and i try to update my table like this:

```
Dim sqlcmd As String = "update Location_tbl set StartTime='" & starttime & "' ,EndTime='" & endtime & "'
```

but error coming like this:

```
operator & is not defined for types 'string' and system.timespan
```

how i can resolve this issue

Comment: What is the data type of `StartTime` column in your table? Also it is much better to use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty The exact datatype is irrelevant to the error.

Comment: Apart from the OP's issue about the & operator, there are real issues about mapping TimeSpan client-side CLR object to a counterpart in SQL Server (or other database) that the OP might not know about yet.  Until SQL Server implements a TimeSpan datatype, Time is the recommended kludge when choosing the SQL Server type, or sometimes integer with some conversions client-side.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty If he's using a different database, he'll have to use the corresponding parameter class -- [OdbcParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter.aspx), [OleDbParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx) etc.

Comment: @ZevSpitz: Yes data type is irrelevant to the error. But it helps to give a proper answer (to do the [TimeSpan.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 starttime.ToString(...)
```

where ... is the format string (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) - it depends on which database you are using. Sometimes you need to use the database function to convert.

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with a database. You're trying to combine a `TimeSpan` variable with a `string` variable. You have to tell .NET how the timespan should be represented as a string, either using `ToString` or `String.Format`.

Once you have your SQL statement as a string, then you can execute the statement.

You might want to consider using parameters instead of concatenating the string into a statement.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should use a [parameterised query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i) - this is good practice because it will make your SQL statement easier to read and you don't have to convert every value to a string. It will also help to avoid a possible [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack on any string inputs you may have.

Secondly how to find a solution depends on what data type these columns are in your database. If they are DateTime or Time then you could potentially use the value as is.

```
Dim sql As String = "update Location_tbl set StartTime= @starttime, EndTime= @endtime"

Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string here"), _
    cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@starttime", SqlDbTypes.DateTime).Value = fromtimepicker.Value.TimeOfDay
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@endtime", SqlDbTypes.DateTime).Value = TotimePicker.Value.TimeOfDay
    Return cmd.ExecuteScalar()
End Using
```

If they are string types then just change the data type to something such as `SqlDbTypes.VarChar` and pass the values with `.ToString` on the end

Side Note; I think you are missing a `WHERE` clause from the end of your sql statement (unless there is only every going to be one row in this table?)

Comment: SQL injection is not the issue here. The OP is starting off from a `TimeSpan`, for which no string formatting is going to contain SQL statements (unless he does `startTime.ToString("{0};DROP DATABASE dbname;--")`. There are still valid reasons to use parameters: 1) to avoid formatting conflicts between the local machine and the server -- mm/dd vs. dd/mm for one, and 2) efficiency, as the server doesn't have to recalculate the execution plan each time.

Comment: @ZevSpitz - agreed although this is good practice. I have updated my answer